# Showing $\sqrt{S^2}$ is a consistent estimator of standard deviation $\sigma$.

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

Given $X_1,\dots,X_n\stackrel{iid}{f}(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$ with population mean $\mu$ and population standard deviation $\sigma$. I want to show $\sqrt{S^2}$ is a consistent estimator for $\sigma$. So if I read my book correctly, we want to show
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|\sqrt{S_n^2}-\sigma|>\epsilon)=0\quad\forall\epsilon >0 $$

So invoking Chebyshev's inequality we have

$$
\begin{align*}
P((\sqrt{S_n^2}-\sigma)^2>\epsilon^2)\leq&\frac{\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{S_n^2}-\sigma)}{\epsilon^2}
\\
={}&\frac{\mathrm{Var}(\sqrt{S_n^2})}{\epsilon^2}\\
={}&\frac{\mathbb{E}[(\sqrt{S_n^2})^2]-[\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{S_n^2})]^2}{\epsilon^2}\\
={}&\frac{\mathbb{E}(S_n^2)-[\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{S_n^2})]^2}{\epsilon^2}\\
={}&\frac{\sigma^2-[\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{S_n^2})]^2}{\epsilon^2}\text{ (Since $S^2$ is an unbiased estimator)}
\end{align*}
$$
This is where I get stuck because I know nothing about the distribution besides it being $\textit{iid}$, so I have no idea what to do with the $[\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{S^2})]^2$ term. I know I need to have a term with $n$ to take a limit, but I am unsure if I have ever taken the expected value of a sample standard deviation or if I even know how to properly. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Just to save time Jensen's inequality is something that I have not learned in the course yet.

Comment: How do you define $S$?

Comment: @jMdA $S=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n-1}}$

Comment: You might find it easier to show $S^2$ is a consistent estimator of $\sigma^2$ first by considering its expectation and then its ditribution

Comment: @Henry would that imply $S\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} \sigma$?

Comment: Since squaring is a smooth function and $\sigma \ge 0$, yes $S^2\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} \sigma^2 \implies S\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} \sigma$

Comment: Thank you- I will give it a shot!

Comment: @Henry Sorry 1 last question, but can I say anything about $S^2$ without knowing if the distribution is normal? I assumed I would take the chi-squared argument but does it apply in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a little more research - here is my answer.

Given $X_1,\dots,X_n\stackrel{iid}{f}(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$, we know that by the weak law of large numbers:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} \sigma^2$$

By the continuous mapping theorem, the square root function preserves continuity, thus

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} \sqrt{\sigma^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{S^2}\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}\sigma$$

It was more theory heavy and that is where I am weak, this has been a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Henry said it all, but I will elaborate here. The sample variance is
\begin{equation}
S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(  X_i - \overline{X} \right)^2,
\end{equation}
and since $X_i \sim f(x;\mu,\sigma)$, the population variance is
\begin{equation}
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(  X_i - \mu \right)^2.
\end{equation}
It is obvious that $\mathbb{E}(\overline{X}) = \mu$ since $X_i \sim f(x;\mu,\sigma)$,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sigma^2}{S^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n-1}{n} = 1.
\end{equation}

Comment: Where does the last limit come from?

Comment: It comes from taking the limit of the quantity $\frac{\sigma^2}{S^2}$ when $n \to \infty$. It is trivial (by definition) to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(  X_i - \overline{X} \right)^2 = \left(  X_i - \mu \right)^2$.

Comment: Thank you guys so much!

Comment: This is grossly incorrect and misleading. Yet somehow OP @Trap.Lord was convinced.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have trouble questioning people when I am unsure myself - just shows that being too cautious is not always a bad thing, either way I posted my own solution below hope it is satisfactory.

Comment: @StubbornAtom please enlighten me and post your correct answer. I'd be delighted to know where I'm wrong.